# Where is the seventh waypoint in Fractured Peaks?

Tags: diablo-iv

There are seven waypoints in the initial Fractured Peaks region but in a complete map from Reddit (below), only six points appear on the map. Where is the seventh?

[image: All seven waypoints]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image: showing all 7 waypoints]

As you can see in the above image, the waypoint on the middle left is obscured by the stronghold symbol.